# Angular HTTP Post doesn't fire

Tags: angular, http, http-post

I can't seen to get this HTTP Post to work. I'm new to angular 4 and this is my first attempt at a post. I can console.log the URL and verified that it is correct.I can also manually use POST in Fiddler and it works correctly, just not from the app.

When I watch fiddler during this action from the app I don't see any attempts at a Post.

This URL doesn't require a body so I wasn't sure if that made a difference.

Component

```
getSanitationTasks() {
    this.sanitationProvider.getSanitationTasks().subscribe(location => this.sanitationTasks = location)
  }

  completeSanitationTask(loadnumber) {
    this.sanitationProvider.completeSanitationTask(loadnumber).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log("complete executed"); this.getSanitationTasks(), error => { console.log(error) };

    });

  }
```

Service

```
 completeSanitationTask(loadnumber) {

    console.log(this.DatabaseName, this.EmployeeNumber, loadnumber);

    this.completeSanitationTaskURL = "http://xxxx-dev.dotfoods.com/api/" + this.DatabaseName + "/v1/sanitation/tasks?employeeNumber=" + this.EmployeeNumber + "&loadNumber=" + loadnumber;

    return this.http.post(this.completeSanitationTaskURL, []).map(res => res.json());


  }
```

HTML

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row style="background: darkblue; color: white;">
      <ion-col col-md-3>
        <ion-label>Door Number</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-3>
        <ion-label>Load Number</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-3>
        <ion-label>Trailer Number</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-3>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row style="border-bottom: solid; border-width: 1px" *ngFor="let task of sanitationTasks;let index = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
      <ion-col col-md-3>
        <ion-label>{{task.DoorNumber}}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-3>
        <ion-label>{{task.LoadNumber}}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-3>
        <ion-label>{{task.TrailerNumber}}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-3>
        <button ion-button (click)="completeSanitationTask(task.LoadNumber)">Complete</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: You have to subscribe to it. See [docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

Comment: It returns an Observable from POST.you have to subscribe to it to get `res.json()` value, However if it's a post request why are you using querystring parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe the observable returned.

```
completeSanitationTask(loadnumber) {
    this.sanitationProvider.completeSanitationTask(loadnumber).subscribe((res)=>{
   console.log(res); 
});

  }
```

Comment: Awesome. I was able to get it to post. How do I get the screen to refresh after the post has completed to reflect the taskmodel now has one less task.

Comment: @JoeStarnes No need to refresh. If the tasks is array of objects then just remove that object from array. Show your tasks code and how your are showing in template.

Comment: The completeSanitationTask is succesfull but the data is not reflected in the view. I added the HTML in the above question. I also added the 2 methods... once that completes and one that loads.

Answer (score 0):

In order to initiate the post http call you need to subscribe to the `Observable` returned by the function.

> The HeroesComponent initiates the actual POST operation by subscribing to the Observable returned by this service method.

Read more in [this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http).

```
completeSanitationTask(loadnumber) {
  this.sanitationProvider.completeSanitationTask(loadnumber)
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I was able to get it to post. How do I get the screen to refresh after the post has completed to reflect the taskmodel now has one less task.

Comment: It might be because of the `trackBy`. Provide JSFiddle, Plunkr or Codepen for further assistance.